# chrom dev tools functions fail when javascript is off by default

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse, google-chrome-console

Starting on Google Chrome version 82 or 83, The autocomplete assistant in the JavaScript console becomes severely limited if javaScript is off by default.

Objects in the window root will be suggested but that is where it ends.

To test, *inspect* an element in the DOM and type `$0.` in the js console. Try it with both, javaScript enabled and disabled. A browser restart is needed to toggle the setting completely.

**My question is, how can I enable JavaScript for all the dev tools while blocking it in new pages by default?**

I should also point out that when JS is disabled by default, the Lighthouse tool is not functional either; and hasn't been for as long as I can remember.

Comment: You should probably report this to https://bugs.chromium.org/.

Comment: This has been reported as Issue 1108021. I was hoping for a quick workaround